# Extracting Neutral sentiment from Huggingface model

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers

I am using Hugging-face pipeline for the sentiment analysis task, which gives me Positive/Negative sentiment along with a confidence score. In my case, I need three outputs (Positive/Neutral/Negative). The problem is that hugging-face is giving me high confidence score even with neutral sentences (such as : 'He have she has')? Any suggestions?

```
from transformers import pipeline
model = pipeline(task = 'sentiment-analysis')
sentence = 'some text to evaluate'
predicted = model(sentence)
print(predicted)
```

Here are some output samples:

```
----------------------------------------------
sentence = 'I love you'
predicted = model(sentence)
predicted
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9998656511306763}]
----------------------------------------------
sentence = 'I hate you'
predicted = model(sentence)
predicted
[{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9991129040718079}]
----------------------------------------------
sentence = 'I have she had'
predicted = model(sentence)
predicted
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9821817874908447}]
----------------------------------------------
sentence = 'I go to work'
predicted = model(sentence)
predicted
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9457777738571167}]
----------------------------------------------
sentence = 'This movie was actually neither that funny, nor super witty.'
predicted = model(sentence)
predicted
[{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9997298121452332}]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [model](https://huggingface.co/models) that does include a `neutral` label, [this](https://huggingface.co/finiteautomata/bertweet-base-sentiment-analysis) model for example:

```
model = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model="finiteautomata/bertweet-base-sentiment-analysis")`
```